# Having an issue sharing process IDs and handles between functions

Tags: c++, winapi

Ive been working on making a memory reader / writer for awhile now and ive ran into some problems.

I made a simple Memory.h / Memory.cpp to handle memory calls.
I have my Main.cpp calling a "GetProcessID" and "OpenProcess". This all works fine.
However i decided to split up things across multiple cpp files.

For instance i have attached some code..

Main.cpp:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Other.h"
#include "Memory.h"

Using namespace std;

Memory Mem;

int main(){

Mem.GetProcessID(ProcessName); // Getting Process ID
cout << "Main.cpp ProcID : " << Mem.ProcID;
TestCall();


}
```

In this i get the process ID I expected.
In Other.h:

```
#include "Other.cpp"
void TestCall();
```

in Other.cpp:

```
#include "Other.h"
#include "Memory.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Memory Mem1;

void TestCall()
{
cout << "Other.cpp ProcID: " << Mem1.ProcID;
}
```

I get both couts come through on console however main displays the ProcID, Other.cpp displays 0 unless i also add:

```
Mem1.GetProcessID(ProcessName);
```

to other.cpp.

Is there a way i can "share" the process id? I also go on to getting base module address and opening a handle. these are also not "Shared". I don't really want to have to open 2 handles, 2 base address calls etc.

Things i have tried...

1) Putting this into Memory.h:

```
class Memory{
Public:
DWORD ProcID;
}
```

incase anyone is wondering... This is my memory.h and memory.cpp

Memory.h (this is in the public class)

```
DWORD GetProcessID(LPCTSTR ProcessName);
```

Memory.cpp

```
DWORD Memory::GetProcessID(LPCTSTR ProcessID) 
{
HWND gWindow = FindWindow(NULL, ProcessID);
DWORD ProcIDBuffer;
GetWindowThreadProcessId(gWindow, &ProcIDBuffer);
return Memory::ProcID = ProcIDBuffer; 
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't `#include` source files. Least of all in header files.

Comment: And please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Ive removed the #includes in my .h files. Thanks. But still no joy, I will keep trying!

Comment: Why do you expect `Mem1.ProcID` to somehow magically acquire the same value as `Mem.ProcID`? Those are two distinct, unrelated variables. When you write `int x; int y; x = 42;` , I assume you don't expect `y` to somehow also get a value of 42.

Comment: The normal ways of sharing state are to take that state as a parameter in the functions using it or to have those functions be member functions of a class containing that state. Are these options not viable in this case?

Comment: In Main.cpp i defined Memory as Mem. In Other.cpp i defined Memory as Mem1

Comment: Those are two different objects. It does not matter if you named them the same or not. They will not share their values.

Comment: I cant define Memory as Mem in Other.cpp as i get the linker error. I thought defining it literally only makes it into a "shortcut"

Comment: Understand what @IgorTandetnik mentioned. That is very important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way: in `other.cpp`, change:

```
Memory Mem1;
```

to:

```
extern Memory Mem;
```

And then change:

```
Mem1.ProcID
```

to:

```
Mem.ProcID
```

But really, you should [read a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Thank you for this. Am i right in saying that because we have already defined Memory as Mem in main.cpp everywhere else will become extern Memory Mem as its already been defined?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  For that reason, it is common to put the `extern` declaration in a header file.